# Sub stringing lat and lng resulted from google maps

Tags: javascript, string, google-maps

I have wrote a code that copies a latitude and longitude precisely by using sub string as the given result from google is a whole string of numbers  - something like this: `"(40.40926169999999, 49.86709240000005)"`.

But  when I search for a location in a map, however when I remove the `console.log()` from the function and then call it later on, it gives me an undefined result, excuse me for the bad English.

code :

```js
test = "(40.40926169999999, 49.86709240000005)"

function cutLat (string)
{
  for (i=0; i<string.length; i++)
    {
      if (string[i] === "," && string[i+1] === " ")
       {
        string.substring(1,i);
       }
     }   
}


function cutLng (string)
{
 for (i=0; i<string.length; i++)
 {
  if (string[i] === "," && string[i+1] === " ")
  {
  string.substring(i+2,string.length-1);
  }
 }
}



console.log(cutLat(test))
```

Comment: You must return something from function: return string.substring(1,i);

Answer (score 0):

Return your final results from the functions.

```
function cutLat (string)
{
  for (i=0; i<string.length; i++)
    {
      if (string[i] === "," && string[i+1] === " ")
       {
          return string.substring(1,i);
       }
     }   
}
```